# boost::optional<> in a union?

Tags: c++, boost, optional-variables

I have an optional POD struct that will be contained inside a union.
`boost::optional<>` holds its type by value, so I thought this could work:

```
union helper
{
    int foo;
    struct 
    {
        char basic_info;
        struct details {
            //...
        };

        boost::optional<details> extended_info;
    } bar;
    //  ...
};

helper x = make_bar();

if( x.bar.extended_info )
{
    // use x.bar.extended_info->elements
}
```

but VS2008 complained that my `bar` struct now [had a copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bd149yt8.aspx) due to the `boost::optional<details>` element.

As a replacement, I've added a boolean flag to indicate whether the optional parameter is valid, but it's clunky:

```
union helper
{
    int foo;
    struct 
    {
        char basic;
        struct details {
            bool valid;
            //...
        } extended;
    } bar;
    //  ...
};
```

I considered implementing `details::operator bool()` to return the `details::valid` variable, but that's obscure and a disservice to humanity.
`boost::optional<>` clearly documents the syntax and intent and doesn't require detective work.

Finally, the `helper` union needs to be POD, so I can't do any dynamic allocation - otherwise I would use a pointer.

Any suggestions for something syntactically similar to `boost::optional<>` that's usable in a union?

Comment: Why can't you use a pointer?  You are allowed to dynamically allocate POD; it just isn't initialized automatically.  Or does your `helper` union need to account for the size of your `bar` struct?

Comment: The union is copied by value and sent as bytes to another process, so I can't share the memory.

Comment: Converting non-POD types into bytes is undefined behavior. You have to use POD types for binary serialization. Actually most do not use binary communication protocols but use XML-based communication protocols these days.

Comment: You are correct.  Unfortunately, this is a legacy product and cannot be easily changed.  I'm eating this elephant one bite at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, the ideal thing to do is to change from a `union` to a `boost::variant<>`.

However, if this isn't possible, you can implement a POD approximation of `boost::optional<>` as follows:

### Implementation

```
template <typename T>
class Optional
{
    T value;
    bool valid;

public:

    // for the if(var) test
    operator bool() const  {  return valid;  }

    //  for assigning a value
    Optional<T> &operator=(T rhs)   
    {  
        value = rhs;  
        valid = true;  
        return *this;  
    }

    //  for assigning "empty"
    Optional<T> &operator=(void *)  
    {  
        valid = false;  
        return *this;  
    }

    // non-const accessors
    T &operator*()   {  return  value;  }
    T *operator->()  {  return &value;  }

    // const accessors
    const T &operator*()  const  {  return  value;  }
    const T *operator->() const  {  return &value;  }
};
```

The const accessors are necessary if you are holding a const instance of `Optional<>`.

### Usage

Like a pointer, `Optional<T>` has no default state and must be initialized before you can rely on it (null or not).
Unlike `boost::optional<T>`, `Optional<T>` cannot be constructed from its `T` value type, and can only be constructed from another `Optional<T>`.
If you really want to value- or null-initialize it at construction, you could make a helper class with an `operator Optional<T>()`.  I chose not to.

#### Construction

```
Optional<details> additional_info;
Optional<details> more_info(additional_info);
```

#### Assignment

```
// if there's no additional info
additional_info = 0;

// if there is extended info
details x;
//  ...populate x...
additional_info = x;
```

#### Data access

```
if( extended_info )
{
    extended_info->member;
    // - or -
    details &info = *extended_info;
}
```

So - it didn't turn out to be too bad.  It doesn't make me feel quite warm and fuzzy, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 14):

You can not use non-POD types as fields in union. Use boost::variant or something like it in C++ instead of union. Leave union only for compatibility with modules written in C.

Comment: Pretty much this- use a boost::variant.

Comment: I have a lot of legacy code that serializes the union into bytes.  I would like to avoid that refactoring right now.

Comment: You have to use the "clunky" helper you described for serialization and convert the variant with optional to and from it. Memory layout of non-POD objects may be optimized by next version/service pack/compiling option of compiler differently, nothing to do.

Comment: mskfisher, take a look at boost:apply_vistor. I use this in my code to serialize boost variants.